# I want to retrieve the width and height of html element with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

How to retrieve the width and height of img element with `HtmlAgilityPack` I do this like this..

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute width = link.Attributes["width"];
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute height = link.Attributes["height"];
```

but the width and height is in most cases null. How to get the css height and width?

Comment: HTML != CSS. Html agility pack parses HTML. It doesn't reconstruct an entire browser with CSS processing etc.

Comment: So how can I get the width and height? any solution?

Comment: please give me some solution. I am really stuck.

Comment: There is no solution for getting height and width of an element using just the HTML source. It's impossible. How big is the browser window? There isn't one. The size of a browser window could affect the size of an abitrary element. Height and width is dependent on the rendering device, which you don't have if you're only considering the HTML source.

Comment: Assuming there is no CSS to modify the height / width of that `img` element, you can get the dimensions if you read the actual image file.

Comment: then how to read the actual img. webclient loading every img element will be too heavy.

Comment: @user1698985 There are plenty of examples of how to download a file with .NET, as well as there plenty of examples for manipulating images.

Comment: @user1698985, you have limited options - either read HTML/CSS specifications (hard route :) ) and implement yourself, or use real browser (i.e. headless PhantomJS, easier route), or ask question specifying you actual goal instead (the easiest route, unless you actually try to render HTML correctly).

Comment: "read HTML/CSS specifications" this STILL will not get you the height/width unless they are part of a fixed layout, which is becoming less and less common since mobile devices are ubiquitous. HTML/CSS is dynamic and depends on the size of the viewport. I am not sure why OP is trying so hard to find a solution to a problem that is missing a critical input variable. This can't be done (and really, the information has no meaning) without a context in which the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Basead in this page: [page](http://www.img.com.br/default.aspx)

```
public sealed class UtilParserHTML
{

    //Private Fields
    private Uri Uri;
    private Stream StreamPage;
    private HttpWebRequest HttpRequest;
    private HttpWebResponse HttpResponse;

    //Public Fields
    public HtmlDocument HtmlDocument { private set; get; }

    public UtilParserHTML()
    {
        if (this.HtmlDocument == null)
            HtmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    }

    public void LoadHTMLPage(string UrlPage)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UrlPage))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("");

        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        this.Uri = new Uri(UrlPage);
        this.HttpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UrlPage);
        this.HttpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;       
        this.HttpRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        this.HttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)this.HttpRequest.GetResponse();
        this.StreamPage = this.HttpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        this.HtmlDocument.Load(StreamPage);
    }

    public void LoadHTMLPage(FileStream StreamPage)
    {
        if (StreamPage == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("");

        HtmlDocument.Load(StreamPage);
    }

    public HtmlNodeCollection GetNodesByExpression(string XPathExpression)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(XPathExpression))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("");

        return this.HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(XPathExpression);
    }
```

Use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) to navigate in html. 
In this case I used this Xpath expression : //div[@class='arrowRibbon'] //img

Look:
**...**

```
this.ParserHTML.LoadHTMLPage("http://www.img.com.br/default.aspx");
            HtmlNodeCollection HtmlNodeCollectionResult = this.ParserHTML.GetNodesByExpression(Page.XPathExpression);

            if (HtmlNodeCollectionResult != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode NodeResult in HtmlNodeCollectionResult)
                {
                    var src = NodeResult.Attributes["src"].Value;
                }
            }
```

**...**

**EDIT**

Look this complete example with width and height:

```
this.ParserHTML.LoadHTMLPage("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp");
            HtmlNodeCollection HtmlNodeCollectionResult = this.ParserHTML.GetNodesByExpression("//div[@class='tryit_ex'] //img");

            if (HtmlNodeCollectionResult != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode NodeResult in HtmlNodeCollectionResult)
                {
                    var src = NodeResult.Attributes["src"].Value;
                    var w = NodeResult.Attributes["width"].Value;
                    var h = NodeResult.Attributes["height"].Value;
                }
            }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This seems to lengthy. I think if I can take Image class and assign the src to its imageUrl property then it should be able to get me the width and hight. What do you say?

Comment: actually I am doing this procedure and it gets the width and hieght and width if it is defined in the html. if it is defined in the css then there is no way to get it.

Comment: I need the css width and height. That is the problem.