# Image height and width in HtmlAgility.HtmlNodeCollection c#

Tags: c#, html, image

I am downloading the whole site html tags and assigned it into HtmlAgility.HtmlNodeCollection c#. Now I am filtering only image src in Html.

This is my code:

```
string responseFromServer = string.Empty;
Uri url = new Uri(requestedURL);
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    responseFromServer = wc.DownloadString(url);
}
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(responseFromServer);
```

So, is there any way to get image height and width or element height and width using HtmlNodeCollection class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.images(v=vs.110).aspx

Replace "src" with "width" and "height"

Comment: Thanks for your reply stanley. I am using  HtmlAgility.HtmlNodeCollection not System.windows.forms.HtmlNodeCollection

Comment: Someone already answer it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782352/i-want-to-retrieve-the-width-and-height-of-html-element-with-htmlagilitypack

Comment: Thanks stanley. In that answer, if there is no width and height attribute in html element then it will return nothing.

Comment: If width and height is nothing, then you must get "src", download the file, load it using Bitmap and read width and height. Otherwise is not possible.